# How can I add a shader graphics to my project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shader-graph

I want to add the shader graphics to my project - [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vrmc.png).
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

By "shader graphics" you probably mean ShaderGraph.

If you write a Shader, you can specify the Folder Structure like this:

```
Shader "Custom/SubFolder/MyShader" {
    Properties{
        _TintColor1("Tint Color 1", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    }

    SubShader{
...
```

Then it will appear in the List from your Screenshot like "Custom -> SubFolder -> MyShader".

Shader Graphs appear under "Shader Graphs" in the List from your screenshot.

To be able to Create ShaderGraphs, you need HDRP or LWRP (now called universal RenderPipeline).

Use a new Unity Version like 2019. Go to Window-> Pakcage Manager and install Shader Graph. Then in Project "Create->Shader->Unlit Shader" for example.

[image]